# Playing an octave lower on the same key

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar

we are doing a song that's originally on the key of F. Our singer would like to sing it on the key of G#. There's an electric guitar solo at the end of the song that I have to play. But after raising everything 3 steps up, nodes appear on the 23rd fret on the 1st string. I am wondering if I can still play the solo on G# and an octave lower. Would that affect the overall of the song? Or is it even correct to do so?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to play *all* the solo an octave lower. For example if the original jumps up a 5th somewhere, jump down a 4th instead to change to a different octave.

Comment: I don't understand 'nodes appear...'  Are you using pinched harmonics, what? And even if they do appear, the location can't be much different from them appearing on fret 20 before, surely?

Comment: @Tim It's almost certainly a misspelling of "notes appear".

Comment: @Tim please don't stop the deep thinking... ...I strongly suspect the OP also didn't actually mean the 6th string but the 1st string, hence your answer is “too correct”. But the terminology is well defined, so I'd say, answer every question as it was literally written – if that turns out to be not what the OP actually meant, their problem, they can always ask a new question.

Comment: @tao it very much depends on the solo in question.  Sometimes you can move parts of a passage down the octave.  Sometimes you might move the whole thing down the octave.  Sometimes you might just change the melody slightly so that it has the same "flavour", but doesn't use the top notes any more.  Care to provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

You can do whatever you want for a solo. Doing it at octave lower will just make it sound lower. It might not sound as prominent as a result. Basically, if you all you can do is play it there then just play it there. You won't be breaking any rules. If you don't like how it sounds there then you can change it accordingly but really how it sounds and feels is all that matters.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try moving some or all of the notes onto different strings. for example, that 23rd fret bottom string appears on the 18th fret of the 5th string. You did mean the fattest string, I hope?